# GAE Proxy "405 Method Not Allowed" when signing into websites

Tags: python, flash, google-app-engine, proxy

First of all, I am a noob when it comes to coding and things like that, so forgive me if any of this sounds stupid. Anyway, using Youtube and Google I managed to get my own Google App Engine Proxy Server up and running. The problem is, it won't let me sign into websites (e.g. Facebook, Twitter, etc.) while using the proxy. I enter the url into the url bar on my website/server whatever you want to call it, and it takes me there without any problems. For example, if I enter Facebook.com into the bar, it takes me to Facebook.com just fine, but when I try signing in to Facebook with my account information, the following message appears:

**405 Method Not Allowed**

The method POST is not allowed for this resource.

No matter what website it is, whenever I try signing in to the website with my account, I get this error. Like I said before, my knowledge with coding is limited, but I somewhat know what I'm doing. I am using Python for the coding.

The second problem I have is that whenever I try to play a flash game it doesn't load correctly, no matter what website it is. Any help?

Comment: The problem is in your source code, which you have not included in the question.

Comment: Where do i find my source code?